# VB.NET function that takes other functions as a parameter, and executes them

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-rpc

Is there a way in vb.net to create a sub/function that will take as an argument some kind of pointer to another function, and allow this new sub/function to execute the passed function?

What I have are 10-12 xml-rpc functions I am calling against a remote server.  Each of these functions has different argument lists (one takes 1 string, another might take 3 strings and one int, etc).  All of them return an object.

As I am calling these, it seems like it should be able to be factored better.  For instance, everytime I call any of these functions, I want to test the return value for a session drop, and do something to try and reconnect to the remote system, etc.

Using .net 3.5

Thanks!

-R

Answer (score 16):

You need to be taken...to [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)'y town

Answer (score 4):

```
Public Sub DoSomething(outerFunction as Func(of T))
    ' do something

    ' call passed in function
    Dim value = outerFunction
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Func<in T, out TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Comment: I edited your answer to make it clearer to other people [reviewing it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11760430) in the review queue that it's not a link-only answer.

Comment: FWIW, I think that the pun in [the answer that came after yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2734209/1364007) which has functionally the same contents probably doesn't warrant the extra 11 upvotes it gets over yours.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I came up with a solution:

Using the CallByName function:

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsc1tx6.aspx)

This allowed me to have one function that actually ran the 12 individual functions, and enabled me to have a centralized error handling system:

```
   Private Function RunRemoteRequest(ByVal functionName As String, ByVal service_url As String, ByVal args() As Object) As Object
    Dim retnVal As Object

    Dim success As Boolean = False
    While success = False And Me._connAttemptCount < MAX_ATTEMPTS
        Try
            retnVal = CallByName(remProxy, functionName, Method, args)
            success = True
            Me._connAttemptCount = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me._connAttemptCount += 1
            If ex.Message = "Error I am looking for" Then
                Me.Login()
            Else
                log.Error("Error in RunRemoteRequest(" & functionName & ").", ex)
            End If
        End Try
    End While

    RunRemoteRequest = retnVal

End Function
```

Note that you need to have Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallType in the module/class you are working on.